# Building (elevated) stairs on a steep slope

Tags: stairs

I'd like to access the hillside in my backyard.  The challenges are:

- Steep hillside
- Lots of maintenance cutting overgrowth
- Walking on the hillside can cause erosion that we wish to avoid

I'd love to build an set of stairs down the hill to make cutting growth easier.  The hillside is *steep* (2:1 grade).

I'd love to use [caissons](https://theconstructor.org/geotechnical/caisson-types-construction-advantages/503/):

- Dig a hole
- Put in a [Sonotube](https://handymansworld.net/sonotubes/)
- Use caisson to attach the posts for [elevated stairs](https://storables.com/articles/how-to-build-stairs-outside/)

[image: Sample Stairs]

I don't understand the best ways to dig the holes for the caissons and how deep to make them.  This [example](https://diydeckplans.com/how-to-build-a-deck/how-to-excavate-post-holes-and-set-posts-for-your-deck) is great for flat ground.

Questions:

1. The best hand tools for this job?
2. The best powered tools (e.g. a rig with a drill?) for this job?
3. Recommended depth?

[image: View of Slope - from Surveyor]

The hillside is primarily a fine-grained sedimentary rock with a high clay content.

[image: Image of the hillside]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149848/discussion-on-question-by-user3533030-building-elevated-stairs-on-a-steep-slop); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.